# Accessing Twitter streams with the Twitter API - in Java

Tags: java, twitter

This is my first time using the Twitter API. I am writing a basic application that when a user types a phrase, it returns the last 15 tweets with the phrase. If they type a user name and click the "search user" button, it returns the last 15 or so tweets from that user.

I believe I have the first part completed, but am a little stuck figuring out how to bring up tweets from a specific user. Any further guidance is most appreciated.

```
package twitter;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Tweet;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;

public class SearchListener extends KeyAdapter implements ActionListener {
    private Button searchButton;
    private Button searchUserButton;
    private TextField searchText;
    private TextArea results;

    private Twitter twitter;

    public SearchListener(Button searchButton, Button searchUserButton,
            TextField searchText, TextArea results) {
        this.searchButton = searchButton;
        this.searchUserButton = searchUserButton;
        this.searchText = searchText;
        this.results = results;

        results.setText("(ready for search)");

        twitter = (new TwitterFactory()).getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSearch();
    }

    private void doSearch() {
        String searchStr = searchText.getText();
        results.setText("searching for:  " + searchStr + "\n");
        if (searchStr == null || searchStr.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        try {

            QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query(searchStr));
            List<Tweet> tweets = result.getTweets();
            int i = 0;
            for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
                results.append("" + i + ":  ");
                results.append("@" + tweet.getFromUser() + " - "
                        + tweet.getText());
                results.append("\n\n");
                i++;
            }
            results.append("" + i + " total tweets found\n");

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            results.append("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // results.append(e.getKeyChar() + "\n");
        if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n') {
            doSearch();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to lookup the user's ID, using their screen name as a key. You can use the following twitter4j method to do this:

[lookupUsers(String[])](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#lookupUsers%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)

Once you have a user ID, you can use the following method to get the last 20 tweets by a user. Note that retweets will not be included.

[getUserTimeline(long)](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelineMethods.html#getUserTimeline%28long%29)